# Use Variable in Command Substitution with cURL

Tags: bash

I need some help with the following simple bash script.
I am getting curl not found error, even though curl is being installed

```
DOMAIN='http://example.com/'
PATH='api/'
BASE_URL="${DOMAIN}${PATH}"

ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "$BASE_URL"'auth/signup' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email": "user@mail.com",
    "password": "password"
}')

echo $ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Well, is `curl` installed? It is not by default.

Comment: Why did you think this has anything to do with using a variable? The message says clearly what the problem is.

Comment: yes curl is installed

Comment: Have you tried typing `curl` in a new shell? If you have configured the path or environment variables in your current session it won't necessarily be available in the subshell created by `$(...)`.

Comment: Also, do you have a sha-bang at the top of your script? Perhaps your script is running in a different shell from the one where `curl` is configured?

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes, I do have it at the top of the script
When I try to execute like this, I am getting the expected result
BASE_URL='http://example.com/api/auth/signin'
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "$BASE_URL" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email": "user@mail.com",
    "password": "password"
}')

echo $ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: See where you have `BASE_URL=${DOMAIN}${PATH}`? That means you redefined `PATH`.

Comment: ...this is part of why you're supposed to use lower-case names for your own variables, so you don't overwrite ones that change the shell's behavior by mistake. If you put your path in `$path` instead of `$PATH` everything would work fine.

Comment: See the relevant POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html specifying the namespace of names with lowercase variables reserved for application use. That's you, developing a script -- you're writing an application, so you should be using the lower-case namespace reserved for your use.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `curl` before assuming it is found

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [[ -z "$(type -p curl)" ]]
then
    printf 'curl not found\n'
    printf 'PATH=%s\n' "$PATH"
    exit 1
fi

# your script here
...
```

Comment: Look at the OP's code -- they've redefined `PATH` to refer to part of their URL.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, that's why I printed it to help them figure out

Comment: Yup. But if they put that before _any_ of their script, as the example shows, then it would also be before whatever's assigning to PATH.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy absolutely true